# how to split json data into strings

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, spring-mvc

i have a doubt that how to split json data into strings.My intention is iam creating several textboxes dynamically and posting them using ajax post,to avoid full postback,here check my ajax part

```
function profileAndSectin_Submit() {
        //alert('test123');
        document.getElementById("hiddenSection").value = i;
        $('#profile_form').submit(
                function() {
                alert(i);
                    var profileName = $('#profileName').val();
                    var Section1 = $('#Section1').val();
                    var dynamicData = " ";
                    for ( var m = 2; m <= i; m++) {
                        var textbx = $('#Section' + m).val();//"Section"+m;
                        var dt="section"+m+":"+textbx;
                        //var txtbxval = document.getElementsByName(textbx).value;
                        var x =  textbx ;
                        if (m <= m - 1) {
                            x + " ";
                        }
                        dynamicData = dynamicData +dt+",";
                        //dynamicData = dynamicData +":"+dt+",";

                    }
                    alert(dynamicData);
                    var Data = "profileName :"+profileName+","+"Section1 :"+Section1+"," + dynamicData;


                    alert(Data);

                    $.ajax({

                        type : "post",
                        url : "addProfile",
                        //data : {
                        //"profileName" : profileName,
                        //"Section1" : Section1,
                        //},
                        data :{"Count" : i,"Data" :Data},
                        success : function(msg) {
                            alert(i);
                            $('#divContent').load('addfields.jsp');
                        },
                        Error : function(msg) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
    };
```

and iam sending these values to one controller ,the main problem comes into picture here,how can i retrive these data,if iam using `@RequestParam("Data")` String data then iam getting the total data as a single string,like

```
{ProfileName:profileName,Section1:section1,Section2:section2...}
```

but i want each string like profileName ,Section2 and Section3 like that i want.

Controller.java

```
@Controller
public class SettingController implements HibernateConfig {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     //public String home(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("Count") int i,@RequestParam("profileName") String pname,@RequestParam("Section1") String Section1,Locale locale, Model model) throws IOException
     public String home(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("Count") int i,@RequestParam("Data") String data,Locale locale, Model model) throws IOException

     {

        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(data);
}
```

so any idea guys?

Answer (score 3):

Use a JSON API/marshaller in Java to transform the JSON string back into a Java object. There are dozens of such JSON APIs: Look at http://www.json.org/ for a list of Java JSON APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, a quick option would be to call in your controller `data.split(",")`. You will obtain a `String[]` with separated values.

In your example the resulting Array will be: `{"ProfileName:profileName", "Section1:section1", "Section2:section2", ...}`.

Afterwards, you can iterate over it and process it as you want.

Comment: where should i use data.split(","), in controller or js

Comment: @srikanth in your controller (I have updated my answer right now). `split(...)` is a java `String` class method.